# Why am I getting a type mismatch error even though the types seem to match?

Tags: arrays, vba, type-mismatch

So I wrote a program that, simply put, takes in a bunch of info, does some moving of said info then tries to pass in one of the arrays into another function which does some math operations.

However, it is saying that there is a type mismatch when I try to call that function (AllODES()). It says it is expecting an array.

Here is the code:

```
Public Function DetermineVolume(x As Double, xmax As Double, Flows As Range, h As Double, error As Double, temp As Double, diameter As Double, pressure As Double) As Double()

Dim i, j, m As Integer
Dim k(9, 9), Y5(9), Y4(9), Y4Old(9), ka(3), Kc(3), MW(7), rho(7) As Double
Dim delta0(9), delta1(9), delRatio(9) As Double, Rmin, FT, vol_F As Double

For i = 1 To 7                                                      'Moving the input data so it can acutally be used
    Y4(i) = Flows(i) 'mol/s
Next i

Y4(8) = pressure

                                                                            'k(Order #, equation #)
    For j = 1 To 6                                                          'First to 6th order


        For i = 1 To 7
            rho(0) = rho(0) + rho(i) * Y4(i)       'Calculate average density of mixture
            FT = FT + Y4(i)
            vol_F = vol_F + Y4(i) * MW(i) / rho(i)      'Calculating the total volumetric flowrate (m^3/s)
        Next i

        rho(0) = rho(0) / FT

        For i = 1 To 8                         'Calculating all of the k(1) values for eq 1 to 8
            k(j, i) = AllODES(x, Y4, i, j, k, h, temp, diameter, vol_F, rho(0)) 
        Next i 'CODE BUGS OUT HERE AND SAYS Y4 is a type mismatch
    Next j

DetermineVolume = Y4

End Function

Public Function AllODES(ByVal x As Double, Y() As Double, EqNumber As Integer, order As Integer, k() As Double, h As Double, _
 temp As Double, D As Double, vol_F As Double, rho As Double) As Double

'Some math operations are done in here

 AllODES=x

End Function
```

So my question is as follows:

What is causing this type mismatch error (because I appear to be passing an array in for an array), and how can I fix this error.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error because you are passing a `Variant` array to a function that is expecting a `Double` array.

You probably intended to dimension them as follows:

```
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, m As Integer
Dim k(9, 9) As Double, Y5(9) As Double, Y4(9) As Double, Y4Old(9) As Double, ka(3) As Double, Kc(3) As Double, MW(7) As Double, rho(7) As Double
Dim delta0(9) As Double, delta1(9) As Double, delRatio(9) As Double, Rmin As Double, FT As Double, vol_F As Double
```